# Call functions randomly in a C++ program

Tags: c++

I have a C++ program in this fashion

```
#include<iostream>

string A();
string B();
string C();

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

I want to test an application by using the three functions A(),B() and C() in such a way that I call them randomly from the main() and in this way I test the application. I do not know if there exists any provision or any tweak which will allow me calling the the functions in any order randomly.

Is it possible in C++ to call functions randomly, if yes then what is the best way of doing it ?

Comment: Make an array of [function pointers](http://www.newty.de/fpt/index.html) and read it in some random order.

Comment: Do you want to call each one in a random order or is call one 3 times an acceptable result?

Comment: `switch rand() % 3`...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about a for loop selecting a random number to control which test is called.

```
for(size_t i = 0; i<NUM_Of_TESTS; ++i) {
  switch(rand() % 3) {
    case 0: A(); break;
    case 1: B(); break;
    case 2: C(); break;
  }
}
```

A switch statement like this would allow for varying function signatures.

Comment: That is a pretty simple idea..Gosh why I could not think about it?? Thanks anyways, I am gonna use it.

Comment: Since NUM_OF_TESTS is already defined for this solution to work, I would recommend updating your solution to use it with the mod operator in place of 3 (i.e. switch(rand() % NUM_OF_TESTS)).

Comment: NUM_OF_TESTS is supposed to be the number of tests you would like to run, not the number of functions you want to test. A(), B(), C(), might have different input variables, or might be random themselves.

Answer (score 5):

If the functions all have the same signature, you can make an array of function pointers.

```
typedef string (*func_ptr)();

func_ptr funcs[3] = { A, B, C };

cout << funcs[rand() % 3]() << endl;
```

Comment: Shouldn't we define the array as `func_ptr a[3]` and they use it as `a[rand() % 3]()`. This kind of construction, if correct, is unknown to me. Could you elaborate on it a little bit? Thx.

Comment: @Mark Ransom There's an error in the function pointer declaration. The name of the variable is missing and you're using the type name as the name of the variable.

Answer (score 3):

Put all the functions in a function array:

```
string(*functions[3])() = { A, B, C };
```

and then call one randomly by its index:

```
int main()
{
    (*functions[rand() % 3])();
}
```

Comment: Surprisingly that is correct. But it would be much easier to read if you threw a typedef in there. Arrays of function pointers are hard to read without so context.

Answer (score 2):

If your functions have the same signature:

Declare an array of functions

```
returnType (*p[3]) (type1 x, type2 y, ...);
```

Initialize the seed of the random number generator:

```
srand (time(NULL));
```

Call the functions as many times as you want in a loop:

```
for(i=0; i < MAX_TIME; i++)    
    p(rand() % 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using C++11:

```
std::vector<std::function<std::string()>> functions = {a, b, c};
std::cout << functions[rand() % functions.size()]() << std::endl;
```